# I installed bad android ROM now phone is screwed over :( any help?

Tags: rom-flashing, rom

Some time ago now I installed an unstable android ROM which I thought was a stock ROM (but it wasn't) so now that I have this crappy ROM on my phone, my camera doesn't work, I can't access all my storage, most apps crash when opening and overall its just a real annoyance. If anyone knows anyway to fix this it would be greatly appreciated if you could tell me! Thanks :)

Comment: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) You know how it works, so why not fix it by installing a "good ROM"? I hardly see any other chance here.

Comment: Izzy I would but for some reason my computer does not recognise my device for some reason when I plug it on via a USB and I can't install the things off the internet so I can't do it that way either :l do you know any other ways of transferring files to an android phone?

Comment: Many, depending on "the device" you keep so anonymous here: 1) use a card reader and copy to SD, 2) use WiFi solutions (which might not work for you due to "unable to access storage"). To name more, it would require more details from your end. I'd recommend creating new questions for solving the multiple issues here: 1) have the device (name? Android version?) recognized by your computer (OS? version?) 2) solve the storage issue (device name, Android version, better description of the problem including error messages).

Comment: ok thanks :) hopefully this will lead to my problem being fixed :D

Comment: I very much hope so! Btw: You can link between your question where it looks helpful to provide context ;)